# How to print the only particular values from xml value by using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, validation, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdCwV.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUBV1.png)I need to print only needed  values of xml  in selenium. If I'm inspecting and printing in console its printing whole data. I need only particular fields and print in console. for reference I attached a

```
String StrPayload = driver.findElement(By.xpath(StrPayloadx)).getText();
System.out.println(StrPayload);
```

Comment: Can you provide output xml text instead of snapshot?
(Try to replace sensitive data by some dummy data)

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<group><UPSSecurity><UsernameToken><Username>pramitjain</Username><A9CDEB6D8DEFC2976</AccessLicenseNumber></ServiceAccessToken></UPSSecurity><ShipmentRequest><ns1:Request xmlns:ns1="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Common/v1.0"><ns1:RequestOption>nonvalidate</ns1:RequestOption></ns1:Request><Shipment><ReturnService><Code>9</Code></ReturnService><Shipper>ama</Name><ShipperNumber>E3F300</ShipperNumber>   Its just printing all this data.. I just need to validate only some fields and print that data serepately like postalcode tag @ Sameer Patil thank you.

Comment: More data is present but comment box is not taking..FIrst im getting all this data printing on console now i should get whatever the tags i want.@SameerPatil

Comment: Can you provide formatted xml (using https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator) snapshot? Else modify description of your question and add xml there

Comment: https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator/cb1621a5

Comment: Please check..@SameerPatil

Comment: I need output XML and not the code which you have written

Comment: Im just printing on console im generating  xml. please check the image in description.. im getting that data in console.Now want split that into different fields one by one in console @SameerPatil

Comment: Unless i get the xml, i can not provide you the way to print each item separately

Comment: https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator/cb431521
This is im printing on console..for reference i have added image.. im automating that page. now should print that values in console. thanks @SameerPatil

Comment: its not printing anything, I thing because  String value = null, script is fine but its not printing @SameerPatil

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56751252/element-is-not-clickable @SameerPatil

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57179504/need-to-get-values-from-xml-and-print-on-the-console can anyone answer this. @SameerPatil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally selenium API does not provide you any way to read xml and create its object or get values from xml nodes. Hence we would need to convert xml text into readable object to get required attribute values.

Following is piece of code where we need to get output xml text and parse to DOM object, then evaluate xpath.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XMLReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String StrPayload = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n"
                + "<group><UPSSecurity><UsernameToken><Username>pramitjain</Username><Password>wismo123</Password></UsernameToken><ServiceAccessToken><AccessLicenseNumber>9CDEB6D8DEFC2976</AccessLicenseNumber></ServiceAccessToken></UPSSecurity><ShipmentRequest><ns1:Request xmlns:ns1=\"http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Common/v1.0\"><ns1:RequestOption>nonvalidate</ns1:RequestOption></ns1:Request><Shipment><ReturnService><Code>9</Code></ReturnService><Shipper><Name>Barak Obama</Name><ShipperNumber>E3F300</ShipperNumber><Address><AddressLine>151 Union St</AddressLine><AddressLine/><AddressLine/><City>San Francisco</City><StateProvinceCode>CA</StateProvinceCode><PostalCode>94111</PostalCode><CountryCode>US</CountryCode></Address></Shipper><ShipTo><Name>Pottery Barn Kids</Name><Address><AddressLine>10153 Monroe Dr</AddressLine><AddressLine/><City>Dallas</City><StateProvinceCode>TX</StateProvinceCode><PostalCode>75229</PostalCode><CountryCode>US</CountryCode></Address></ShipTo><ShipFrom><Name>Barak Obama</Name><Address><AddressLine>151 Union St</AddressLine><AddressLine/><AddressLine/><City>San Francisco</City><StateProvinceCode>CA</StateProvinceCode><PostalCode>94111</PostalCode><CountryCode>US</CountryCode></Address></ShipFrom><PaymentInformation><ShipmentCharge><Type>01</Type><BillShipper><AccountNumber>E3F300</AccountNumber></BillShipper></ShipmentCharge></PaymentInformation><Service><Code>03</Code><Description>UPS Ground</Description></Service><Package><Description>Self Service Return</Description><Packaging><Code>02</Code></Packaging><PackageWeight><UnitOfMeasurement><Code>LBS</Code></UnitOfMeasurement><Weight>51</Weight></PackageWeight><ReferenceNumber><BarCodeIndicator>1</BarCodeIndicator><Value>W191006849</Value></ReferenceNumber></Package></Shipment><LabelSpecification><LabelImageFormat><Code>GIF</Code></LabelImageFormat></LabelSpecification></ShipmentRequest></group>";
        //Get DOM
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xpf.newXPath();
        DocumentBuilder db;
        Document xml;
        String value = null;
        try {
            db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            xml = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(StrPayload.getBytes("utf-8")));
            value = (String) xpath.evaluate("/group/ShipmentRequest/Shipment/Package/ReferenceNumber/Value", xml, XPathConstants.STRING);
        } catch (SAXException | IOException | ParserConfigurationException | XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(value);
    }    
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Value is: W191006849
```

What you need to do is, use code below string 'StrPayload' in your selenium code.
Also make sure that **xpath** you are using to get value should be correct. You can use absolute and relative xpath both as per your convenience.

Let me know if this helps. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your Answer sir.. But If I inspect the element and print it in console the whole xml values is printing .. first I should print that. I cant give manually in eclipse the printed value. now it should convert into string and split into different value like as you printed in console.. partially ur anser is right but manually we can't give StrPayload.. Im keeping it as an xpath holderString StrPayloadx = "//*[@id=\"kibana-body\"]/div/div/div/div[3]/discover-app/main/div[2]/div[2/div[2]/section[2]/doc-table/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]";.  https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator/cb1621a5

Comment: My code would work if your code "String StrPayload = driver.findElement(By.xpath(StrPayloadx)).getText();" gives you XML string while executing your selenium script.

Comment: /group/ShipmentRequest/Shipment/Package/ReferenceNumber/Value
Do We want to need to follow the order to print other values?? @SameerPatil

Comment: This is called as absolute Xpath. You can use relative xpath (which needs to be unique) to fetch exact value required. Check for xpath tutorial for more info.
Example - https://stqatools.com/selenium-absolute-relative-xpath/

Comment: One last question If i want print value and also Accountnumber tags how can i print in different lines.Thanks @Sameer Patil

Comment: xpath.evaluate("/group//PaymentInformation//AccountNumber", xml, XPathConstants.STRING)
This will give you account no. store this in a variable and print

Comment: Hi I have other xml in the same page..first one is working fine and able pruint.. for the second xml doing the process but its not printing the data in console @ Sameer Patil

Comment: Can you write xpath for item Id /Output//Item//ItemID
/Output//Order//OrderType
MultiApi/API/Output/ItemList/FirstName. Can you please me to write dz xpaths..@Sameer Patil

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56752952/need-to-write-the-data-in-the-last-column-of-excel-sheet-with-header-and-value can you answer this. @Sameer Patil

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158048/need-to-click-by-using-if-condition @Sameer Patil