# Need to click by using if condition

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

[image][image]I have an interface name in my page, so I need to click on that interface element.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='kbnDocTableOpen__button']"));
        WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[contains(text(),'STR_PGW.RETURN')])[1]"));


    try {
        boolean value = element1.isDisplayed();
        if (value == true) {
            element.click();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not clicked");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);

    }
```

I need to click exactly where the STR_PGW.RETURN interface is present,On that button need to click

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: I need to click on the arrow buton only when the Str_Pgr_Return interface is present in that line. @Guy.

Comment: I have added another picture for reference, pls check..

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see any [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) element in the code you provided hence I doubt that anyone will be able to come up with the locator unless you share full code of the [table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) you're trying to automate. And the chance of getting the comprehensive answer will be much higher if you post [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) as the code, not as the picture.

So far I can only recommend:

1. Consider using [Table](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/htmlelements/blob/master/htmlelements-java/src/main/java/ru/yandex/qatools/htmlelements/element/Table.java) class available via [HtmlElements framework](http://htmlelements.qatools.ru), it makes table-related operations much easier
2. If you don't want or cannot go for HtmlElements - you can locate the button using [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes), it would be something like (reference only, I do not guarantee the success unless I see the full table code)

   ```
   //td/descendant::span[contains(text(),'STR_PGW.RETURN')]/parent::tr/td/descendant::button[@class='kbnDocTableOpen__button']
   ```

   See [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) for more XPath-related tips and tricks