# Need to get values from Xml and Print on the Console?

Tags: java, xml, selenium

[image]I want to print the values on Console, I'm unable to print the values on Console and not throwing any error
This is my code:
    public void payload(WebDriver driver, BaseTest basetest) throws Exception {
        List PayloadXml = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[@ng-repeat='field in fields']"));
        System.out.println("payload");

```
    for (WebElement P : PayloadXml)
        System.out.println(P.getText());

    List<WebElement> PayloadXmlvalues = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='kbnDocViewer__value']"));
    String payload = "<CreditReturnRequest>";
    for (WebElement V : PayloadXmlvalues)
        System.out.println(V.getText());

    for (int i = 0; i <= PayloadXmlvalues.size(); i++) {
        // System.out.println("Content text is : " + PayloadXml.get(i).getText());
        // match the content here in the if loop
        if (PayloadXml.get(i).getText().contains(payload)) {

            String xmlvalues = PayloadXmlvalues.get(i).getText();
            String xmlOutputFile = "data.xml";

            try (FileWriter writexml = new FileWriter("src/main/data.xml")) {
                writexml.append(xmlvalues);



            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xpath = xpf.newXPath();
            DocumentBuilder db;
            Document xml;
            String value = null;
            String OrderNumberXml = null;
            String ShipperNumber = null;
            String Name = null;

            db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            xml = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlvalues.getBytes("utf-8")));
            value = (String) xpath.evaluate("/CreditReturnRequest//Request//req:Payment//BillToKey", xml,
                    XPathConstants.STRING);
            OrderNumberXml = (String) xpath.evaluate("/CreditReturnRequest//Request//req:Payment//OrderNo", xml,
                    XPathConstants.STRING);
            ShipperNumber = (String) xpath.evaluate("/CreditReturnRequest//Request//req:Payment//PaymentKey", xml, XPathConstants.STRING);
            Name = (String) xpath.evaluate("/CreditReturnRequest//Request//req:Payment//ShipTokey", xml, XPathConstants.STRING);

            System.out.println("value:" + value);
            basetest.test.log(Status.INFO,value + "TransactionNumber Printed value successfully");

            System.out.println("Order Number:" + OrderNumberXml);
            basetest.test.log(Status.INFO,  OrderNumberXml+ "TransactionNumber Printed value successfully");
            System.out.println("ShipperNumber:" + ShipperNumber);
            basetest.test.log(Status.INFO, ShipperNumber + "TransactionNumber Printed value successfully");
            System.out.println("Name:" + Name);
            basetest.test.log(Status.INFO,  Name + "TransactionNumber Printed value successfully");
            }

            break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Check for your list of webelments .size() property.  If the xpath is not valid, or for whatever reason, does not return any elements, your array will be empty and not make even one pass, nor report any error.

Comment: can you show some code here, it can be helpfull Thanks @BillHileman